# Referencing extended variables from the user model after authentication successful

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, static

So, I have extended the base django user model using a one-to-one field:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')
    user_avatar = models.ImageField(storage=site_media_upload_location, null=True, blank=True)
```

Upon authentication the following displays correctly other than the user_avatar variable from the user model:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  <div class="user">
    <div class="user-image">
      <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ request.user.userprofile.user_avatar.url }}" alt="User Avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown user-dropdown">
    Hello,
    <a href="#" aria-expanded="true">{{ request.user.first_name }}<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu text-left">
      <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
{% else %}
Do something else
{% endif %}
```

My `MEDIA_URL` is defined in the settings.py file as

```
MEDIA_URL = "/site_media/"
```

This is purely where every "users" avatar will be stored for development purposes.

I've tried a few combinations, none of which seem to work:

```
<img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ request.user.userprofile.user_avatar.url }}" alt="User Avatar">
```

...and this...

```
<img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ request.userprofile.user_avatar.url }}" alt="User Avatar">
```

..and this...

```
<img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ request.user.user_avatar.url }}" alt="User Avatar">
```

If anyone knows how I can reference the variables of an extended model after authentication success I would be greatly appreciative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')
```

to:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
```

and this:

```
src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ request.user.userprofile.user_avatar.url }}"
```

should work.

When you call `request.user`, that object tries to get the property `userprofile` set by the `related_name`. You have set the `related_name` to `user`, so `request.user` didn't have the property `userprofile`.

Comment: Wow - it worked! Amazing how some just know this sort of stuff...although, my own CSS stylings are a little off - I have one massive image! XD Haha, thank you!